# Why does complex conjugation permute the rows (columns) of a character table

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, characters

> If $\chi$ is the character of $\rho$, then $\overline{\chi}$ is the character of $\rho^*$ (dual) and $\chi_{irreducible} \iff \overline{\chi_{irreducible}}$.
>
> This implies complex conjugation permutes the rows of a character table.

I cannot see why it is implied that complex conjugation would permute the rows of a character table. Why should the dual also be in the character table?

Nor can I see why complex conjugation swaps columns. It is just stated in my notes without any explanation.

I cannot find a good explanation in notes online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that the "dual" of an irreducible character is indeed an irreducible character:

**Hint** (mechanical). 

Think about row orthogonality and how the inner product is defined (remember the set of irreducible characters is an *orthonormal basis* for the set of class functions).

**Hint** (representations). 
Define a map $GL(V) \to GL(V)$ by sending a matrix $(a_{ij})$ to $(\overline{a_{ij}})$, that is, taking the complex conjugate of each of its entries. Is this an automorphism of $GL(V)$ when $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$?

Comment: I still dont get it from these hints. Also are you saying that as the "dual" is another (different) character it must therefore also feature in the character table?

Comment: If an irreducible character $\chi$ takes any nonreal values, then yes, the conjugate $\chi^*$ is an irreducible character distinct from $\chi$. So if you take conjugates of an irr. char., you get back an irr. char.; that's exactly what a permutation (of rows) does; swaps the characters around.

Comment: Ok. So how does the first hint work?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming we are talking about finite groups. Then we have: $\rho(g)$ is orthogonal, therefore diagonalizable. Since $\rho(g)^{|G|} = 1$ the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are roots of 1, this means that their inverses, which are the eigenvalues of $\rho(g^{-1})$ are their conjugates and therefore      $\overline{\chi(g)}$ is $\chi(g^{-1})$

Comment: wouldn't it be more standard to say that $ \rho(g) $ is unitary rather than orthogonal?